# Is it possible to run Zend Studio + Debugger over MAMP Pro 2.x on OS X Lion?

Tags: php, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I've just upgraded to Lion, then I had to upgrade MAMP to 2.x, along the way I lost the ability to debug in Zend Studio.

I read on the MAMP blog that they dropped support for Zend Extensions... does this mean that they have also dropped support for the Zend Debugger?

If so, what are my options?

Cheers
Ant